# Factory using threadlocal

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I am running into some factory defined like the following:

```
T* TFactory::getThreadLocalT() {
  static ThreadLocal<T> threadLocalT;
  return threadLocalT.get();
}
```

I am wondering why we use thread local within the factory? Would the following be sufficient? Is it because we don't need to lock if we use thread local? It seems not thread safe if T has stage even if we use thread local?

```
T* TFactory::getT() {
  static T someT;
  return &someT;
}
```

Comment: Both examples are thread-safe, but they are not directly comparable as they achieve different goals. Apparently, the goal of the first example is to create a separate instance for each thread, rather than a single global instance.

Comment: but if T has some states it won't be thread safe for the global singleton case, right? Neither is the thread local version right?

Comment: Also I know they are different, but more importantly, why? What's the pros and cons?

Comment: Creation of the singleton instance is thread-safe, in both cases. This feature is sometimes referred to as [magic static](http://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/c-plus-plus/magic-statics). Again, it doesn't make sense to talk about pros and cons of two techniques that achieve entirely different end results. Presumably, the design of the overall program that uses the first approach requires an instance of `T` per thread, not a single instance shared by all threads. Why the design so requires, I of course can't tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks! @Igor. When I asked about thread safety, I am not referring to the creation of the object. In the singleton case, I have a global shared object. Thus when I access it, I need to lock it. In the thread local case, do I need to lock it?

Comment: Not unless the calling code subsequently shares it with other threads.